# I get error while downloading utilities module - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to download **`utilities`** module with **`pip install utilities`** but i get this error

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement utilities (from versions: none)
>
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for utilities

Python Version : 3.8.2

OS : Windows 10

Comment: If you can give more information, like your Operational System, it would be better for the post, and maybe help more people with the same problem.  Long-life to Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

try with this command:

python3 -m pip install utilities

Comment: Tried again sir, still nothing happens